# append a div to body and a script to the div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to append `div` to the body and then append a script to the `div`. so here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function(){

        var $div = $('<div/>').appendTo('body');
        $div.attr('class', 'div-bla');

        var $script = $('<script/>').appendTo('div-bla');
        $script.attr('text', 'alert('yay')');

    }); 
});
```

but it's not working at all, what is wrong here?

Comment: You can run JS there after appending the `div` right. Why injecting `script`?

Comment: If it were to work you would want $script to contain the js, not $div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn").click(function(){
     var $div = $('<div/>').appendTo('body');
     $div.attr('class', 'div-bla');

     var $script = $('<script/>').appendTo('.div-bla');
     $script.text('alert("yay")');
   }); 
});
```

Comment: Glad to help @adamwest

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to resolve this - one option is to pass the `$div` to the `appendTo()` method directly like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function(){

        var $div = $('<div/>').appendTo('body');
        $div.attr('class', 'div-bla');

        var $script = $('<script/>').appendTo($div); // <-- Update this line
        $div.attr('text', 'alert("yay")'); // <-- also update this line to avoid a syntax error

    }); 
});
```